Was promised a position to be turned away
I applied for a promotion with my current employer and was accepted into the 16 week training program in preparation for the role. In the beginning, I knew relocation was possible after completing the program. I was informed during the interview process that after completeing the program I would still have to apply for the actual position at sites that have availability in which I can still be denied.
Part two of the interview process with the District Manager, she specifically said the position is yours if you want it. She went on telling all other employees she hope I choose to stay at her site concluding training. I was so happy to hear this because it brought me great relief to know I can have the position I desired and don't have to relocate.
There is only 5 openings for this position. When I started there was 3, one got terminated, which left 2 permanent and 2 trainees including myself totaling 4. Half way through my training she direct hired 2 others leaving only one position available between us 2 trainees.
After successfully completing the training program, I did my initial interview and was rejected. She gave the position to the other trainee who openly exclams he's in a relationship with one of the higher ups children.
She won't give me a direct explanation as to what happened and yet admitted to me she strung me along because she was hopping corporate allowed her to keep all 6 of us.
I was left scrambling to locate a nearby site which I discovered dont have any available openings. I did not apply to any openings because I was lead to believe I had the position at her site. If she would've not lead me to believe I had a place here I wouldn't have left my last position on a possibility of this promotion. She stating I can stay as long as I need until I get an accepted offer but that means I'd be working for less pay as my counter parts and who knows how long that will take.
And to add insult to injury they took my assigned work vehicle and gave it to a new hire. I have never be disciplined for anything nor was my performance brought into question.
I need to know if there is something that can be done about this. I'm in fear I am about to be out of a job and I can't go back to my last position because there is no openings.

What exactly is your question? " I need to know if there is something that can be done about this." Done about what exactly? You not getting the position ? The DM promising things she could not keep? A competitor with personal ties being preferred? One of the positions being terminated? There are so many "this" in your question it’s hard to say what you want in practice.

Sorry, but this is hard to follow. It would be helpful to set up a time line and clearly described what contracts/paper-work was signed at these steps and what they say. It sounds like at some point your original employment contract was terminated or modified but I can't tell when and how.

You seem to have all the information. There is very little we can do for you here. You need to see a lawyer in your juristiction to go over your specific contract to see whether this was legal or if you are owed some compensation.

separately from what you can do for yourself and legally, you might at some point want to write a review for that employer on a job site to help warn others ... that's the lowest effort lowest impact (but at least some) action you imho can take (just stick to the facts and consider doing it anonymously)

Sometime the manager has plan and the higher manager come and shuffle them, it seems your situation. The manager plan seems to keep you, but somehow she got instruction from higher up to hire X. Now you and her are in a bad position, she cannot say tell you her plan was screw by higher up and you are scrambled. She seems to be in good faith because she try to give you a job even if it pay less.

I attest this unfair situation multiple times and often the person lose his job when he try to retaliate. Now your priority is stabilizing your job because of budget, she cannot hold this favor for long time, good luck!

Location matters. This is really a question for a labor lawyer, but likely there is no point.
Likely there is nothing that you'll be able to do.
I am assuming that there is no written contract that says otherwise, so they don't have to keep you employed. It isn't fair that they gave the job via a nepotism.
Good luck on finding a better job.

A contract is an agreement, it doesn't need to be written, only evident.  (not a lawer)
